# Reindexing cron not executing at specified time

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to execute cron job of reindexing at specified CST time but not working, so anyone let me know what to do?

Thanks
Ketan

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the cron syntax which you have set. There may be a problem in the cron_schedule table that the last cron was stuck and not able to run any cron after that.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your time but i solved this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can setup the cron by using below steps and it can work as specific time slot.

(* * * * *)

1 "*" min(0-59),
2 "*" hours (0-23),
3 "*" day of month (1-31),
4 "*" month (1-12),
5 "*" day of week (0-7)